# How to create a dynamic table for addition using Express and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a table where the number given in the url for example:

```
localhost:8000/add/:num
```

where the num is value given and it will create a table with rows which should contain the sums of all possible numbers from 0 to :num.

server.js

```
 app.get('/add/:num', function(req,res) {
      console.log(Number(req.params.num)+ Number(5));
      res.render('add.hbs', {
                number_1: 5,
                number_2: req.params.num,
                sum: Number(req.params.num)+ Number(5)
              });
    });
```

add.hbs

```
 {{#each users}} 
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{number_1}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{number_2}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{sum}}
        </td>
      </tr>
   {{/each}}
```

Now I can render the HTML table but i cannot dynamically add rows when a specific number is given on the URL. So if the number is passed as 2, it should add 0 + 1 onto one row, 1 + 2 onto the next row. I know i need to create a helper function in order to render that on the .hbs file but i cant figure out the logic behind it.

Comment: i think you data argument is object not an array

Comment: How to achieve that without putting {{each}} around the row then?

Comment: I was actually looking to put the value on the URL and create a array upto the given number and then use that to create rows.

Comment: if you want to  put the value on the URL , you can pass this value by separates (Like 
 1,2,3   1|2|3   )   then you retrieve and split them

Comment: No, it will just take 1 number in the number and then calculate the sum from zero upto that number